# pandas, python: collecting, using and saving real time data

Tags: python, pandas

In the Python (2.7.9) code below, I am receiving real time stock data via callbacks through TWS API and IBpy.  As the data of interest, **bid, ask, last price, and last trade size** comes in, it goes into a pandas (0.16.1) data frame.  Also, I have added a column to the data frame 'bidVol' where the last few lines of code place the running sum of trades or volume done at the bid price.  Currently I get the total shares exchanged at the bid for a given stock in the 'bidVol' column.  I would like to replace the single 'bidVol' column with 78 columns, one for each total generated over the five minute intervals of a trading day.
How would I:

1) create additional columns with clock time headings for 5 minute intervals between 9:30 and 4:00 pm, so the headings of the data frame look like:

'symbol', 'security', 'exchange', 'currency', '9:30', '9:35',..., '3:55'

2) then put that sum of volume for trades done at the bid price during a given time interval into its respective column?

```
 from __future__ import print_function
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy
 from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
 from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
 from ib.ext.TickType import TickType as tt
 from time import sleep

 # establish universe of stocks to watch...

 contracts = pd.DataFrame([
        ['FGEN', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD'],
        ['AAPL', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD'],
        ['GILD', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD'],
        ['INTC', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD'],
        ['MSFT', 'STK', 'SMART', 'USD']

 ])

 # create column names for DataFrame

 contracts.columns = ['symbol', 'security', 'exchange', 'currency']

 # add specific column names to match name returned by tickType.getField()
 contracts['bidPrice'] = 0
 contracts['askPrice'] = 0
 contracts['lastPrice'] = 0
 contracts['lastSize'] = 0
 contracts['bidVol'] = 0
 def error_handler(msg):
        print(msg)

 def my_callback_handler(msg):
        if msg.field in [tt.BID, tt.ASK, tt.LAST]:
               # now store response in the data frame
                 contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, tt.getField(msg.field)] =   msg.price
        elif msg.field in [tt.LAST_SIZE]:
                 contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, tt.getField(msg.field)] = msg.size
                 if msg.field == tt.LAST_SIZE:
                         if contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, 'bidPrice'] ==    contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, 'lastPrice']:
                        contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, 'bidVol'] += contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, 'lastSize']

                             print(contracts.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following code near the top of your code:

```
from datetime import *

def fivemin():
    """Generate time string in 5 minute intervals"""
    dt0 = datetime.now()
    dt1 = dt0.replace(minute=5*(int)(dt0.minute/5),second=0,microsecond=0)
    return dt1.time().strftime('%H:%M')
```

Just above the definition for `error_handler`, add the following:

```
ds = datetime.now().replace(hour=9,minute=30,second=0,microsecond=0)
for i in range(79):
    d_i = ds+timedelta(minutes=5*i)
    contracts[d_i.strftime('%H:%M') = 0
```

Then replace your `contracts...bidVol` line with the following:

```
contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, fivemin()] += contracts.loc[msg.tickerId, 'lastSize']
```